# Why does this piece of code yield a parse exception, when using parsec, but not with Graham Huttons simple example library?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I recently tried to get into parsec, and I stumbled upon a Video that explained the basics of functional parsing. A simple demo library was shown, whose syntax looked similar to parsec. Function composition worked very similar. This snippet worked correctly with the library. Yet, if I run this piece of code with parsec, it gives me a parse error, (unexpected character)

```
module P where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

int :: Parser Int
int = do
    x <- many digit
    return (read x)

expr = do
    x <- term
    char '+'
    y <- expr
    return (x+y)
  <|> term

term = do
    x <- factor
    char '*'
    y <- term
    return (x*y)
  <|> factor

factor = do
    char '('
    x <- expr
    char ')'
    return x
  <|> int
```

I don't quiet understand where the difference is

Comment: Do you have the snippet that fails? The likely difference between the two libraries is backtracking: most example parsers do quite a lot of backtracking, but for performance reasons (and because it can give better error messages), parsec doesn't.

Comment: The backtracking is in `expr`. Both alternatives start with `term`. Likewise in `term`, both alternatives start with `factor`.